# Use htaccess to redirect Wordpress to static website in a subfolder

Tags: redirect, htaccess, static-website

I've used Simply Static plugin to create a static copy of my WP website. All the files are in `/2016/`, and the static copy is in `/2016/a/`. What should I add to `.htaccess` in order to make WP redirect from `example.com/2016` to `example.com/2016/a`?

This is my current `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /2016/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /2016/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: "to make WP redirect" - It's not really making "WP redirect" is it? Don't you just want to redirect (or rewrite?) all requests to your now "static copy"? Do all your internal URLs include the `/a` subdirectory? Or are they all relative to current directory?

Comment: @MrWhite, you are exactly right. I want to redirect all my requests to the static copy. All the URLs are relative to the current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an *external redirect* from `/2016/<anything>` to `/2016/a/<anything>`, then you can do something like the following *before* the existing WordPress directives (ie. before `# BEGIN WordPress`) in your `/2016/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\d{4})/(.*)
RewriteRule !^a/ /%1/a/%2 [R,L]
```

The negated `RewriteRule` *pattern* prevents the redirect from occurring when the URl-path already starts with `a/` (relative to the `/2016/` directory). The `%1` and `%2` backreferences refer back to the matched *CondPattern*.

Note that since this is an *external redirect*, the `/a` subdirectory will naturally be exposed to the user. (If you are internally linking to the `/a` subdirectory then it's exposed anyway.)

---

Alternatively, if you want to *internally rewrite* all requests from `/2016/<anything>` to `/2016/a/<anything>`, and thus hide the `/a` subdirectory (the user only sees `/2016/<anything>`) then you can do something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %(ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS) ^$
RewriteRule (.*) a/$1 [L]
```

The `RewriteCond` directive that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable makes sure that this is only applied to the initial request, not the rewritten request, in order to prevent a rewrite loop.

Note that this *rewrite* will rewrite the URL regardless of whether `/a` is already present on the initial request. eg. a request for `/2016/a/<something>` will be *internally rewritten* to `/2016/a/a/<something>` (which I assume would probably result in a 404). But if the purpose is to hide the `/a` subdirectory then `/a` shouldn't be present on the request in the first place.

Again, this *must* go before the existing WordPress directives. The WordPress site is no longer accessible until these directives are removed.

If URLs of the form `/2016/a/<something>` have already been indexed, or linked to by external third parties then also consider including a redirect to remove the `/a` subdirectory from the URL (in order to preserve SEO). For example, the following would need to go *before* the above rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %(ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS) ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\d{4})
RewriteRule ^a/(.*) /%1/$1 [R,L]
```

The `%1` backreference refers to the directory name ie. "2016" (captured in the preceding *CondPattern* - this simply saves having to manually hardcode the directory name in the *substitution*. `$1` is a backreference to everything that follows `/2016/a/` in the URL-path.

---

Note that the above "redirects" (indicated by the `R` flag on the `RewriteRule`) are temporary (302) redirects. If these are intended to be *permanent* then change `R` to `R=301`, but only after you have confirmed it's working OK. 301s are cached hard by the browser, so can make testing problematic.

Comment: Where exactly to add this code? It doesn't work if I add it at the very beginning, after <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> or after RewriteBase /2016/

Comment: Sorry, I had assumed your `.htaccess` file was located in the document root, but as you say "All the files are in `/2016/`" - I've updated my answer. (Incidentally, you don't _need_ the `RewriteBase` directive or the `/2016/` prefix on the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ if the `.htaccess` file is located in the `/2016/` subdirectory itself, but one or other would be required if the `.htaccess` file was in the document root.)